# Steam Games bought in Japan, and their fate

Tags: steam

I am currently living in Japan, and bought couple games already. At the moment about to buy "Middle-earth: Shadow of Mordor", but on Japanese Steam Market, its name is "Middle-earth: Shadow of Mordor (JP)" with a small warning that says game includes Japanese language support. So I will be buying the Japanese version, but will there be any limitations afterwards? If I want to play again from another country? Also 90% of the same game's DLC's are N/A in Japanese store. Please can someone help me what the heck is wrong with Japan?

Comment: Generally Steam only restricts what you can buy not what you can play based on where you live. The exception are games bought in certain "cheap" regions (eg. Russia and many former Soviet republics), which can only be played in those regions. Games though sometimes though impose their own restrictions through their own DRM. I don't know if that's the case for the special game you're looking at. Note that regardless of whether or not you can play it, many Japanese versions of games on Steam only support the Japanese language, and don't support English even if the game originally did.

Comment: If you have doubt or if the game you want is only available in japanese on steam, you could buy your games in their international version on an online retailer which provides steam games as activable CD keys. Before buying on these website ensure that the game could be activated in the region of your steam account.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In the case of Shadow of Mordor, the only limitation is that you can only play the game in Japanese or English. The international version supports many more languages (but not Japanese).

Usually, region locks will be noted on the store page. However, since it falls to the publisher to add this information, it's not always present.

One way to make sure is to add the game to your inventory as a giftable copy first, then inspect it. If there are any play locks, it will look like this:

[image: Steam restricted gift]

If it's not restricted, you can then activate it; otherwise, [request a refund](https://support.steampowered.com/kb_article.php?ref=6695-QIKM-7966).

Comment: How about this situation? N/A items...

http://i.imgur.com/ynsRfnW.png

Comment: I think you'd have to ask Warner Brothers on that one. It's probably an accident or missing price information. Honestly, if you have someone with a non-Japanese Steam account handy, asking them to gift you the international GOTY edition is probably your best option if you want the DLC. It costs about the same as the Japanese base game, but has all the DLC.

Comment: But international edition cannot be activated in Japan it says. Sucks here :(